# Vim color scheme trouble after update

Tags: vim, color-scheme

I'm having trouble with vim color display lately. On vim version 7.2, it worked perfectly but ever since I updated to vim 7.3, default load of most colorscheme is not what they look when you give the command `:colorscheme <name>` after vim has loaded.
Eg, this is how vim looks when I put `colorscheme default` in my .vimrc  [image]

While this is how it looks when I type `colorscheme default` *after* vim has started.  [image]

Same is the case for all light colored themes.
Is there a workaround for this, maybe some changes in the theme file would do. Is there a difference between the new 7.3 and the old 7.2 version in color display?

Comment: You could try setting `set background=light` which adjusts some colours to make them readable on a light background. However, I don't know why this behaviour would have changed between 7.2 and 7.3.

Comment: doesn't work either. Seems colorschemes are unable to load the background which they normally do when you type in the vim prompt (tried for a few others)

Comment: What does `:colorscheme` say immediately after starting Vim 7.3?

Comment: @IngoKarkat : it says the name specified in .vimrc correctly

Comment: I updated my answer (quit a lot), hope it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I changed this answer totally**

I have done some research (I also had some issue with color schemes, recently starting using it in MS Windows).
With the color schemes that are in a default installation I think the only issue would be with `default` since that is not setting `background` (from here I use the short form `bg`), only using `set bg&`. That is "guessing" what the background should be. GUI is loading **after** both `.vimrc` and `.gvimrc`, and before that the "guess" would be incorrect.
See the VIM manual for [`Options`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27background%27)

> When setting 'background' to the default value with:   :set
>   background& Vim will guess the value.  In the GUI this should work
>   correctly, in other cases Vim might not be able to guess the right
>   value.
>
> When starting the GUI, the default value for 'background' will be
>   "light".  When the value is not set in the .gvimrc, and Vim detects
>   that the background is actually quite dark, 'background' is set to
>   "dark".  But this happens only AFTER the .gvimrc file has been read
>   (because the window needs to be opened to find the actual background
>   color).  To get around this, force the GUI window to be opened by
>   putting a ":gui" command in the .gvimrc file, before where the value
>   of 'background' is used (e.g., before ":syntax on").

This should be the solution according to that:

```
gui  " Before your line with syntax on
syntax on
```

Either in `.vimrc` or `gvimrc`, doesn't matter (if you don't use it for different environments).
If you don't want to change the order of loading you can try this instead

```
autocmd GuiEnter * set background&
```

Both works for me.

But if this doesn't help I think there must be some plugin that is messing it up.
And for clarity; `set background=dark` is **not** setting the background to dark, it's telling vim to adjust colors for a dark background.

There is no information in the question of the environment, or what plugins that are used. So it's some kind of guessing here.

Comment: Thanks, but still same as previous before :-/

Comment: Strange, I have the same behavior as you describe, and it helps with doing as I suggest. Are you using more than one color scheme? Do you have some own color/highlight commands in `.vimrc`? Does it matter what file type you are loading? Try with some other extension to see what is causing this (and try that with my suggestion).

Comment: Yep, some plugin seems to be interfering. Gvim is now working fine, and vim works fine if I clean up my vimrc and put an empty one with colorscheme specification. I've added quite some plugins lately, something might have messed up. Thanks @244an, I made you research a lot :P

Comment: @piyush: I am learning VIM so the research was interesting for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have no clue what could cause this, but as a workaround you could put the `:colorscheme <name>` command into your `~/.gvimrc` (for GVIM), or use the following autocmd in your `~/.vimrc`:

```
autocmd VimEnter * colorscheme <name>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Putting `set background=light` helped. But I've also noted that order is important I mean that in _vimrc file command `set backgroung=light` should be after command `colorscheme default`.

Comment: actually the plugin "vim-easymotion" was causing troubles for me. Removing that plugin helped :)